# Cannot download generated files

Tags: files

I have a site (Linux/Drupal/Apache) that generate a .xlsx file from custom code and its saved to files, but after that I cannot download it from drupal, it give permission denied.

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access xxxxxxx.xlsx on this server.
```

The upload file is saved with -rw------- or 600 permission, and the user/group from Apache.

If I chmod the file to 644 it works.

How can I made that any file generated in that way, will be -rw-r--r-- or 644 ?

Comment: What upload method are you using?

Comment: File not uploaded, its generated from code. Question edited.

Comment: Ok, so provide the code you're using to generate and save the file.

Comment: I think you should modify the permissions of the folder containing the files. The files should inherit access rights from the parent folder.

Comment: container folder have 755 permissions, but the newly created file its not inheriting permissions, as its being created as 600.

Comment: Have you tried changing the folder permissions recursively?

Comment: That will not fix future generated files...

Comment: If the access rights and file / folder owners are properly configured the files should inherit the rights of the parent folder

Comment: If I create a file manually on that directorie, the file inherit permissions properly, also check with umask, but files created with PHP are not follow that, and create files with 600 insted of 644.

Comment: Okay so the access rights are not the problem. Can you describe how you create the file? Maybe provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. make sure there is no .htaccess rule that is preventing the download
   (it may be inherited).
2. If using file entity check: /admin/config/media/file-settings and make sure .xls is allowed.
3. Could be blocked by server security like modsecurity rules, check the apache logs...

Answer (score 0):

Execute a *drush status-report* and see if you have any problems that Drupal detected.

If not comfortable with drush, navigate to [yoursitename]/admin/reports/status and see if you have any action items (highlighted in red)

> How can I made that any file generated in that way, will be -rw-r--r--
>   or 644 ?

You can check your default perms by executing *umask* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). It is usually 0022. If it is something like 0077, then you will have to change it, if it isnt then dont worry about it right now.